# can Qt signal wakeup sleeping thread

Tags: qt, signals, wakeup

I'm working on some application using Qt framework, it uses serial port and need to receive some data, problem is that data is organized with some protocol, which i parse in readyRead() signal handler(slot), at the same time, i need to wait for parsed message with some timeout. So, to wait, i use QThread::msleep() after sending, but i've noticed, that when thread goes to sleep in msleep(), readyRead will be emitted only after msleep() will be finished. My question is, why readyRead can't wake up thread? Qt signal is not working like real Unix signals?

Comment: Why would you want to do a sleep? If you use a QThread to manage your thread, it has its own event loop that does nothing until it gets a signal. You don't need to sleep manually, the QThread's event loop will do that automatically for you.

Comment: Cross-thread signals are processed by the receiving thread's event loop, which the sleep () blocks. There's no way to interrupt a blocking call with a Qt signal.

Answer (score 1):

If you have single thread application `readyRead` slot not executes immediatly you got data on port. Read about `Qt::QueuedConnection` in `QObject::connect()`. When `readyRead` signal emits in serial port class it just added to queue of events (in global event loop). All events will be executed later by `QEventLoop` (inside QApplication instance).

Looks like you sleep your main thread so `QEventLoop` cant execute anything while sleeping. In this case you need to read your port from another thread to avoid main thread sleeping.